# Sequence of loops making indefinite program

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program that takes all the combinations of a dice (got that part done) but now I am trying to take all the combinations and put them in an array by there total ( (1,1) = 2, (2,4) = 6 ) and I will eventually implement it into a game. But when trying to organize them I created an infinite loop that does not seem like it should be running infinitely.

```
    for (int dice1 = 1; dice1 < 7; dice1++)
     for (int dice2 = 1; dice2 < 7; dice2++)            
         for (int j = 0; j < 6;)
         {
            msg = "";
            msg = "(" +dice1 + ", " + dice2 + ")";
            arrayDice[dice1 - 1][dice2 - 1] = msg;
            add = dice1 + dice2 - 2;
            arrayAdd[add][j] = msg;
            if (add == 10 - j)
                j = j + 1;
         }
```

the arrayDice is just the array of all combinations while the arrayAdd is all the added combinations. I really can't find where the problem is coming from.

Comment: You should try and run a debugger on this, and examine the value of `j` in each iteration.

Comment: What happens when `add != (10 - j)`?

Comment: `if (add == 10 - j)
                j = j + 1;` is not executing enough times to break out of the third loop...

Comment: add != (10 - j) Doesn't change anything but I am trying to make it run more now

Comment: I think you're missing my point - if that `if` statement doesn't evaluate to true, then that's where your loop is hanging. There's a simpler way to accomplish your goal, however, and it depends on how you want to represent it, but to that, I'd recommend a 3D array to simplify things.

Answer (score 2):

Third `for` loop in your program is the one that is running infinitely. In the third loop, you are not incrementing the counter 'j' within the `for` statement but you increment it within the body of the loop. However, the only place in the body of the third loop where the counter 'j' is increasing is within an `if` statement - `if (add == 10 - j)`. Since you start this loop with j=0, the expression 10 - 0 = 10 for the first iteration while the variable 'add' is 1 + 1 -2 = 0. So this expression `if (add == 10 - j)` evaluates to false. So j never gets incremented. The only other variable in this expression is 'add' which doesn't get changed until you come out of the third loop. So in short the expression `if (add == 10 - j)` never evaluates to true and hence j is never incremented resulting in the third loop running infinitely.

Comment: but when add = 10 shoudn't j go up one? (when dice1 = 6 and dice2 = 6)

Comment: With your current code, 'add' never becomes 10.  You have add = dice1 + dice2 - 2. And dice1 and dice2 never exceed 0 because of your third loop running infinitely.